# Textarea won't submit to MySQL with wysiwyg editor?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm trying to format some texts from the textarea using a rich text editor.

However, every time I hook up the editor to my textarea, the textarea doesn't submit it's data to MySQL database and it is frustrating to sat the least.

**PHP code:**

```
if (isset($_POST['answer'])) {

    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['id']);
    $answer = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['answer']);

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare(
        $db_conx,
        "INSERT INTO forum_answer(answer)VALUES(?)"
    );
    //after validation, of course
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $answer);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    if (mysqli_affected_rows($db_conx))
    {
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);//<-- CLEAN UP AFTER YOURSELF!
        //update was successful
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="mypage.php">
    <textarea class="rte-zone"  name="answer" cols="45" rows="3" id="answer"></textarea>
</form>
```

Rich text editor that I am using: [THIS IS THE RICH TEXT EDITOR](http://batiste.dosimple.ch/blog/posts/2007-09-11-1/)

My PHP code works fine without the rich text editor and it will store the textarea data into the MySQL database fine but it will stop working as soon as I hook it up to the text editor.

The main reason I need to use a text editor is to format the textarea texts before i enter them into the MySQL database so I can use the data in another HTML page format.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `<textarea>` name is `a_answer` but your PHP code is looking for `answer`

Comment: @MikeW, edited my question. sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: Have you tried to echo it and see what's being submitted without inserting into db?

Comment: Do you have a submit button?

Comment: @AbuNooh, echoing it doesn't return anything same as it doesn't insert the data into the mysql database. it will work fine without the editor though.

Comment: @CullenJ, Yes, i do. i stated that it works fine without the editor.

Comment: I guess some how the editor is overwriting your field name maybe. You could try extract() post to see if anything is being sent at all albeit with a different name. Have you seen the rendered html to see if the field name is the same or overwritten?

Answer (score 0):

I may be way off base here but It is my thought that the rich text is the problem: it is throwing in markup code and corrupting the text (id and/or answer). In example, you are trying to enter "lor Ipsum data ect..." in bold or other markups which would which would render: (depending on the type of rich txt editor).....

```
<b>lor Ipsum data</b> or <strong>lor Ipsum data </strong>
```

And there is also a possibility of 2 suggestive next line characters     **/n** or a "**br**"    as well based on the rich text editor (from the rows=3).
The

```
<b> and </b> or the /n or <br>
```

might be causing the problems due to the special characters.

It would be my thought that if the "answer" has no need of formatting (stored in the database, stick to the plain text, then if needed reformat that text in html or other when retrieved if such be the case.

referance ---[php real escape string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

If I am not mistaken, unless you code mySQL li **special characters**, MySql Li looks filters or rejects certain character items that could parse into  markups that could be considered sql injection.

I also noticed that you are offering an **ID** but no code to handle that code and insert.

```
  "INSERT INTO forum_answer(answer)VALUES(?)"
```

what about the ID in the database, if it is unique ID, I get that, but if you are logging then it may be a required field.